BIOS and MMIO Controller
I am trying to understand MMIO in x86 architecture. I read that there is an MMIO controller that converts physical addresses to MMIO or RAM access, and that this chip is configured by the BIOS. My question is: How does the BIOS configure this MMIO? I know that BIOS code is written in assembly, but which instructions are used for this configuration? (I assume it can't be used mov for this purpose.) I arrived at this question by looking at how Linux obtains memory mappings, which can be seen in /proc/iomem. I also want to ask that.
